# BeautifulSoup is not reading the html components inside section tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrap data from the following link.:https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/298226251/subform-a-modern-tool-for-digital-product-designer/community
 But while executing the this code:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

url= "https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/298226251/subform-a-modern-tool-for-digital-product-designer"

html=urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
urlcampaign = url+str("/community")
html=urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

table = soup.findAll('section',attrs={"class":"js-project-community-content js-project-content project-content"})
print table
```

It returns:

```
[] or null
```

And I checked the text in the soup and found out that

```
<section class="hide js-project-community-content js-project-content project-content">
</section>
```

This section tag which hold a lot of the page's content,does not hold any text or data inside while scraping, but the webpages displays everything perfectly fine.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you doesn't read from `.../community` because you use `url` instead of `urlcampaign`

Comment: @ymonad, check my answer (regarding the `class1 class2 class3`).

Comment: @Dekel sorry i forgot the presence of `hide`. i should delete the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the soap to find this element you should use:

```
attrs={"class":"hide js-project-community-content js-project-content project-content"}
```

> Note the `hide` that was missing there

If you want to select the `section` tag with multiple classes it will be much better to use the CSS selector:

```
soup.select('section.js-project-community-content.js-project-content.project-content')
```

This way you don't have to provide the complete value of the `class` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You create `urlcampaign = url+str("/community")` but later you use `url` to read page so you don't read from `.../community`